# render the response in the mid of a servlet

Tags: servlets, httpresponse

I wanted to know how I can render the response(basically my HTML) in the mid of a servlet processing.. since the response is always rendered only at the end of the servlet, meaning once all commands are executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet 3.0 has [asynchronous support in servlets](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3). This means you can render the response and do some other tasks after the response was rendered.